# lofJSidernews slides don't show, animation not start

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a misterious problem with this script. You can check it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/netdjw/jM4fs/3/). My code look like the on the official demo page, but it doesn't woring fine.

I'm using `lofJSidernews` 3.0.2 with `jQuery` 1.8.3

Now I don't have any error messages or warnings in console log. I'm not see how can I debug this thing.

Any idea?

Comment: By default jQuery doesn't support 'easeInOutQuad' method, you need to include plugin which support it, as e.g jQuery UI, see: http://jsfiddle.net/jM4fs/4/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include jQuery easing plugin and it should works as expected:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jM4fs/6/)**

Comment: better, but not perfect. The content frame still doesn't work.